# If the customer pays less than the ticket price

Tags: java, if-statement

Help me here i tried make success , program but theres a mistakes here can?
any one  solve it and send it ,
If the customer pays less than the ticket price, I want to print the money less than the ticket price and print the rest to pay, or if the customer pays more than the ticket price, the rest of the money is printed to the customer, and finally if he pays the ticket amount, you print welcome

```
    import java.util.Scanner;

 public class Flow {

    static Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    static int age;
    static double ticketpricetax = 0.15 * 100 + 10;
    public static double remainigamount = ticketpricetax;
    public static double howmuchpay = 10;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println("Age");
        int age = input.nextInt();
        if (age > 12 || age <= 50) {
            System.out.println("ticket price is ");
            System.out.println(ticketpricetax);
            System.out.println("Please pay your ticket");
        }
        input.nextInt();
        if (ticketpricetax > howmuchpay) {
            System.out.println("the money less than ticket price");
        } else if (ticketpricetax > howmuchpay) {
            System.out.println("the money is greater than ticket price");
        } else {
            System.out.println("welcome");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: anyone solve it and send it? No, be specific about where the error is, and we'll help you fix it.

Comment: `ticketpricetax > howmuchpay` appeared twice

Comment: The outcome of the second `input.nextInt()` is not stored in a variable so you will always compare 0.15*100+10 with 10.

Comment: I don't know where the error is, but I want the program to print well !!!

Answer (score 1):

Your price input is not stored in any variable and it should be double not int, and then you are comparing ticketpricetax and howmuchpay with their initialized values,howmuchpay is not updated with input. In addition you're making an incorrect check and missing some statements.
Here is the correction :

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Flow {

static Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
static int age;
static double ticketpricetax = 0.15 * 100 + 10;
public static double howmuchpay = 10;

public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.out.println("Age");
    int age = input.nextInt();
    if (age > 12 || age <= 50) {
        System.out.println("ticket price is ");
        System.out.println(ticketpricetax);
        System.out.println("Please pay your ticket");
    }
    howmuchpay = input.nextDouble();
    if (ticketpricetax > howmuchpay) {
        System.out.println("the money less than ticket price");
        System.out.println("rest of the money to pay = "+(ticketpricetax-howmuchpay)); 
    } else if (ticketpricetax < howmuchpay) {
        System.out.println("the money is greater than ticket price");
        System.out.println("rest of the money = "+(howmuchpay-ticketpricetax));
    } else {
        System.out.println("welcome");
    }
}
}
```

Comment: If you want to use the money difference later you can assign it in the two if-statements to a variable.

Comment: Hi    guys i want              if the ticket price 10$
and he pay 8$,
i want he pay to arrive the target.
10$.

example ;

ticket price 10$
and he pay only 5$
 print to him rest money to pay ,
5$ and if he pay it , print to him welcome .